# Android make searchbox in actionbar instead of searchview

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a searchbox in the actionbar just like the facebook android app or instagram instead of the search button you click to open a searchbox i don't know how to implement this in my actionbar tab fragment, Please any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the doc linked below, you might just need the same SearchView but just set it to not be iconified by default.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
```

Comment: Dude You're The Best Man this code work's. Ahh You saved my life